# What does this empty threading class do?

Tags: python, multithreading

In this example, there's a threading subclass defined that I don't think does anything.

```
class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        return

class otherClass(baseClass):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        bar

def main():
    t = threadClass()
    t.start()

    oc = otherClass()
```

What does ThreadClass do?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It is a perfect example of empty thread that ends instantly. Also, should be t = ThreadClass(), case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html and look at the 16.2.1. Thread Objects section, I am pretty sure you will find the answer.

ThreadClass shows you the basic usage of writing your own class by deriving it from threading.Thread. It would make more sense if you try to do something in the run()

By writing your own class by deriving it from threading.Thread, you can have more flexibility for your own multi-thread tasks.